Gnome 3 custom app launcher
I downloaded an Appimage and I have it in ~/.local/bin/the_app.appimage. Of course, I can run the app from the terminal with .local/bin/the_app.appimage, but I want to create a launcher for this, i.e. I want to create an entry for this app in this menu:

I added a the_app.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications as it is pointed out here with the following content
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=the_app
Exec=~/.local/bin/the_app.appimage
Comment=Just an app
Terminal=false

but it does not show up in the applications menu. I already tried restarting my PC.
How can this be done?
